# Location of VPython library

Tags: python, vpython

Where is vpython installed?

When I enter in the terminal the command: pip install vpython,There are some processes in the log, but in the end I don’t see any files of this library in the root folder of the project, but at the same time I can import this library in the code

Answer (score 0):

Like most Python modules, you'll find it in Lib/site-packages/vpython within your Python installation.